# Parsing time with DateTimeFormatter "hh:mm a" cause Exception

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

I have already checked many solutions online but still got the exception when parsing "hh:mm a".

In JSP:

```
$('#t2').timepicker({
                        timeFormat : 'hh:mm a',
                        interval : 30,
                        maxTime : '11:00 pm',
                        startTime : '08:00 am',
                        dynamic : false,
                        dropdown : true,
                        scrollbar : true
                    });

...

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label
                                            class="col-md-3 control-label">Start
                                            Time</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-7">
                                            <input type="text"
                                                class="timepicker"
                                                id="t1"
                                                name="startTime"
                                                readonly="readonly">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

In Java:

```
String startTime = request.getParameter("startTime");
DateTimeFormatter formatterTime1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.US);
LocalDateTime localStartTime = LocalDateTime.parse(startTime, formatterTime1);
```

Exception:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '08:00 am' could not be parsed at index 6
```

Even when I tried to hardcode:

```
String startTime = "08:00 am" (08:00am, 8:00am);
```

It has the same problem.
Even in a single test file.
Is it because Java 8 cannot parse time only String?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to [Meno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38880379/438154)'s answer, you'll need uppercase `AM` or `PM` or a case insensitive `DateTimeFormatter`, which you can build as

```
String startTime = "08:00 am";
DateTimeFormatter formatterTime1 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
   .parseCaseInsensitive().appendPattern("hh:mm a").toFormatter(Locale.US);
LocalTime localStartTime = LocalTime.parse(startTime, formatterTime1);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can parse "hh:mm a" to a `LocalTime` but not to a `LocalDateTime` because there is no date information. Why should the parser wildly guess any arbitrary date for you? My suggestion leaving the choice which date to choose:

```
LocalTime localStartTime = LocalTime.parse(startTime, formatterTime1);
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDate.of(...).atTime(localStartTime);
```

In contrast, old `SimpleDateFormat` uses the default date 1970-01-01, the date of UNIX epoch. But I don't think this is a reasonable design decision of old API and was only motivated by parsing to an instant-like instance of `java.util.Date` (due to missing time-only type like `LocalTime`).

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues,as mentioned by Meno

- You are using LocalDateTime instead of LocalTime
- pattern letter 'a' means you need to specify AM/PM in uppercase, unless you use DateTimeFormatterBuilder ex:

  `LocalTime localStartTime = LocalTime.parse("08:00 AM", formatterTime1);`